# Swapping Handlebars for Angular in MEAN app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I'm building a MEAN app with user authentication and I'm currently in the process of learning Angular (I like to learn by using whatever it is I'm learning in a practical way). Anyway, before I stripped the handlebars view engine and changed the view files from .hbs to .html I was able to display the username of the currently authenticated user like so:

**Handlebars:** `{{user.username}}` = req.user.username  and it displays the username of the current authenticated user.

Rather than using render for rendering my pages, I'm now using sendfile:

```
app.get('/dashboard', Auth.ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./app/views/admin.html', req);
});
```

I'd like to know how I go about rendering the username of the currently authenticated user in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the user info by

1. Setting a global variable using your handlebar template.

   ```
   app.get('/dashboard', Auth.ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
       res.render('admin',{user: user});
   });
   ```

   And in handlebar template add something like below

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        window.user = {{user}};
   </script>
   ```

   wrap this global in angular service

   ```
        angular.module('myApp').service('Global', ['$window', function($window){
            function _getUser() {
                return $window.user;
            }

            return {
                user: _getUser()
            };
        }]);
   ```

   Now in your controller, you can access the user data by injecting Global service

   ```
      angular.module('myApp').controller('AdminController', ['$scope', 'Global',    function($scope, Global) {
          $scope.user = Global.user;

      }])
   ```

   User will be available in your angular partial views.

   ```
   <div data-ng-controller="AdminController">
       Welcome <span ng-bind="user"></span>
   </div>
   ```
2. or you can send the information via cookie. After reading the cookie value inside _getUser function in angular service, delete the cookie.
3. or you can send an ajax request for fetching the data inside angular service.